# How to make multiline comments for Isabelle theory?

Tags: isabelle

Rosetta provides documentation only for the single-line comments for Isabelle https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Comments#Isabelle

I read https://euromils-project.technikon.com/downloads/Deliverables/Y2/2015-EM-UsedFormalMethods-WhitePaper-October2015.pdf Section 2.2.4 that suggests text{* ... *} or --{* ... *} for the multiline comments but they are not working in my theory:

```
theory Max_Of_Two_Integers
  imports Main
begin

function two_integer_max :: "nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat"
  where
 "two_integer_max first second =
     (if (first > second)  then
        return ()
      else
        return ())
--{* "two_integer_max first second =
     (if (first > second)  then
        return first
      else
        return second)"
*}
text{* "two_integer_max first second =
     (if (first > second)  then
        return first
      else
        return second)"
*}

end
```

gives

```
Malformed command syntax
```

for both blocks of eventually commented code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 kinds of comments in Isabelle:

1. Source comments. They are removed from the source code:

   ```
   (* "two_integer_max first second =
         (if (first > second) then
           return first
         else
           return second)"
   *)
   ```
2. Document comments. They become part of the document when the Isabelle document preparation mechanism is used. In the simplest form they look like:

   ```
   ― ‹ "two_integer_max first second =
        (if (first > second) then
           return first
         else
           return second)"
   ›
   ```

   Note that the leading symbol is a long dash (it can be inserted as `\<comment>`) and the angle brackets are also special, not just `<` and `>` (they can be inserted as `\<open>` and `\<close>`).

The variant with `text {* ... *}` is not a comment, but a part of the document text, used when generating the document from the theory:

```
text {* "two_integer_max first second =
     (if (first > second)  then
        return first
      else
        return second)"
*}
```

Isabelle 2021 warns about the syntax and suggests using *cartouche* (the brackets `‹...›` mentioned above):

```
text ‹ "two_integer_max first second =
     (if (first > second)  then
        return first
      else
        return second)"
›
```

*Note.* The original example misses a closing double quote after the final `return ())`.